# Create Folder in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I'm new to swift and I'm not sure how to make a new folder from a string path (or from some kind of `File/ NSFile` object)

This is on OS X with Cocoa.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My understanding is that you are trying to create a directory programmatically using swift. The code given below does the same.

```
    var err: NSErrorPointer = nil
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    manager.createDirectoryAtPath("/Users/abc/Desktop/swiftDir", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: err)
```

Comment: What if the user isn't called "abc"? What if the user is running on a network and has a completely different location for his file system. Rather than making assumptions about the user's file system, use the tools to ask for the location of special directories.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid snippet which answers OP's question. Would it better if the sample path was "/foo/bar/baz"?

Comment: You can use `NSHomeDirectory()` to get the home directory anyway.

Comment: You can also use '~', no?

Answer (score 6):

**Xcode 8 • Swift 3**

```
extension FileManager.SearchPathDirectory {
    func createSubFolder(named: String, withIntermediateDirectories: Bool = false) -> Bool {
        guard let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: self, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return false }
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url.appendingPathComponent(named), withIntermediateDirectories: withIntermediateDirectories, attributes: nil)
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
if FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.desktopDirectory.createSubFolder(named: "untitled folder") {
    print("folder successfully created")
}
```

---

[SearchPathDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager.searchpathdirectory)

Comment: I'd use `first` instead of directly accessing the first object with a subscript `[0]`. One returns an optional, the other causes a runtime error if the array is empty.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 2.0 you must use the new style for error handling:

```
let path: String = "/Users/abc/Desktop/swiftDir"
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
do
{
    try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print("Error while creating a folder.")
}
```

Comment: Hi JavaNut. I know that the terminator in this case is not neccessary, but the print syntax is something else, what changed in swift 2.0: My intension was to show, that print("Error while creating a folder.", terminator: "\n") is the new syntax of the print command and if you do not give a terminator, a new line is printed after the text. So someone can learn of showing it in the full syntax. The print command above has differenz meanings in Swift 1 and Swift 2. I wanted to avoid confusion about this.