# How to hide sqlite files in shared folder in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, shared-directory

I make application with shared folder. User can to save some data in Core Data. I know that it saved in sqlite and it shown in the shared folder. I want that user doesn't see it. How can I hide this sqlite files in shared folder that user will not delete they via iTunes?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a period in front of the file name to make it hidden.

Just rename it from

```
whatever.sqlite
```

to

```
.whatever.sqlite
```

Comment: But all the same will it be shown in shared folder? Or how to make it programmatically?

Comment: @Alexsander I didn't understand your question. I Said if you name a file or a folder starting with a period it will be hidden

Comment: I want that user doesn't see it

Comment: I download this project from App Store and I can see it.

Comment: And I want to hide these files from user.

Comment: You can create a hidden folder and put all files inside

Comment: With help NSFileManager?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27756077/2303865 I will update that answer to Swift 2.0

Comment: Thank you! You very helped me.

Comment: That only makes it invisible by convention. You can still see the file.