# Save NSImage as png in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cgimage

I'm trying to create and save a `.png` from raw pixel data.  I create an array of `UInt8` where each number is a rgba value, kinda like this: `[r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a...]`.  I can use this array to create a `CGImage` just fine.  I can even use the `CGImage` to create an `NSImage`. The `NSImage` displays how I expect it to display when its loaded into an `NSImageView`.

What I want to do is to save an `NSImage` to disk. I've tried calling `TIFFRepresentation` on the `NSImage` and saving the `NSData` to "~/Desktop", but no file is saved.  Any thoughts?

```
var pixels = [UInt8]()

for wPixel in 0...width {
    for hPixel in 0...height {
        pixels.append(0xff)
        pixels.append(0xaa)
        pixels.append(UInt8(wPixel % 200))
        pixels.append(0x00)     
    }
}

let image = createImage(100, height:100, pixels: pixels)
let nsImage = NSImage(CGImage: image, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
NSBitmapImageRep(data: nsImage.TIFFRepresentation!)!.representationUsingType(.NSPNGFileType, properties: [:])!.writeToFile("~/Desktop/image.png", atomically: true)



func createImage(width: Int, height: Int, pixels:Array<UInt8>) -> CGImage{
    let componentsPerPixel: Int = 4; // rgba
    let provider: CGDataProviderRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil,
                                                                   pixels,
                                                                   width * height * componentsPerPixel,
                                                                   nil)!;

    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue)

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitsPerPixel = 32

    let bytesPerRow = (bitsPerComponent * width) ;

    let cgImage = CGImageCreate(
        width,
        height,
        bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow,
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo,
        provider,
        nil,
        true,
        .RenderingIntentDefault
    )

    print(cgImage.debugDescription)
    return cgImage!;
}
```

Comment: You need to expand tilde in path

Comment: how to get the desktop url http://stackoverflow.com/a/27756077/2303865

Comment: I remember now I already tried that.  I get: "CGImageDestinationFinalize failed for output type 'public.tiff' " and also
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Make sure you are not using playground to test it. Don't force unwrapp your optionals. Get rid of your !!!s

Comment: I'm not.  Its a simple mac app. Also tried it as a command line tool.  Same error both times.

Comment: I changed all the !!! to "if let unwrapped = stuff {}" type things.  That got rid of one error.  However, I still get "CGImageDestinationFinalize failed for output type 'public.tiff'"

Comment: Is it TIFF or PNG?

Comment: I'm trying to save a PNG.  I'm not sure where public.tiff is coming from.  I googled around and I can't find anything on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29263098/2303865

Comment: Yeah, I found that exact same thread earlier.  I'm doing basically the same thing with NSBitmapImageRep(data: nsImage.TIFFRepresentation!)!.representationUsingType(.NSPNGFileType, properties: [:])!.writeToFile("~/Desktop/image.png", atomically: true)

Comment: Another strange thing is that after I call "nsimage.TIFFRepresentation" any NSImageView using nsimage suddenly turns black, despite nsimage.TIFFRepresentation being read only.

Comment: This latter problem may be result of deeper memory management issue. You're calling `CGDataProviderCreateWithData`, but you're not providing an function to release the memory. If you `malloc`'ed it, you'd just leak, but it's worse in this case. When `pixels` falls out of scope, the memory previously associated with it is now available for other purposes even though the `CGDataProvider` is referencing it. I prefer to call `CGBitmapContextCreate` with `nil` for the data parameter and get the system generated buffer with `CGBitmapContextGetData`. It gets you out of the memory management weeds.

Comment: Interesting.  So I create a CGContext with no data, and then pass it into CGBitmapContextGetData and that returns an unsafeMutablePointer<void>. What do I do with that?

Comment: With `CGBitmapContextCreate`, "In iOS 4.0 and later, and OS X v10.6 and later, you can pass `NULL` [for the `data` parameter] if you want Quartz to allocate memory for the bitmap. This frees you from managing your own memory, which reduces memory leak issues." Then `CGBitmapContextGetData` can be used to get access to that buffer so you can fill the pixels as you so choose. But you don't have to manage this memory. The OS will.

Comment: By the way, rather than `writeToFile(atomically:)`, I'd generally suggest `writeToFile(options:) throws`, so if there was an error writing to the file (e.g. maybe this is sandboxed app), you'll be notified what the issue was.