# Write Image To File in Directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager, writetofile

I am getting an error when writing an image file to a directory in Xcode. The function `data.writeToFile` is returning an error. Here is what I am trying to do:

Get The File Path:

```
func getPath(fileName: String) -> String {
        let documentURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
        let folder = "sampleDirectory"
        return documentURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(folder).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).path!
    }
```

Save the Image

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage, path: String) -> Bool {
        let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        do {
            let success = try pngImageData?.writeToFile(path, options: NSDataWritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return false
    }
```

However, there is an error saying:

```
NSPOSIXErrorDomain - code : 2
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

EDIT
Where I call the code:

```
let fileName = "first_image"
let imagePath = self.getPath(fileName)
let result = self.saveImage(processedImage, path: imagePath)
```

processedImage is of type UIImage!

Comment: iOS device or simulator?

Comment: iOS device is where this happens.

Comment: Could you please add `saveImage(..)` call code?

Comment: I edited it. Not sure if it will help much though.

Comment: You need to `return success == true`

Comment: @LeoDabus, Sorry how can it fix an error?

Comment: I think that he should just create and return a NSURL and use writeToURL

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan it was not about the error. He is never returning true there.

Comment: The error is in the catch statement, not in the return of the function. The writeToFile function throws an error.

Comment: @MehtaiPhoneApps take a look at this answer on how to append a directory to URL http://stackoverflow.com/a/34701970/2303865

Comment: @MehtaiPhoneApps be aware that success is optional Bool there so you need add `== true`

Comment: NSPOSIXErrorDomain code 2 means - no such file or directory, right? If so - try do debug in that way...

Comment: @LeoDabus your solution did not fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan do you know what the problem could be? I'm not sure why it is saying this. Do you need to create the file or directory? Is it not automatically created for you when you write to it?

Comment: @MehtaiPhoneApps looks like you've never created the folder http://stackoverflow.com/a/27756077/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I think that is it, let me try.

Comment: The problem was solved, @LeoDabus thank you.

Comment: @MehtaiPhoneApps you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the directory "sampleDirectory" if it does not exists or don't use a subdirectory. 
You can check if the directory exists with:

`if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {
    // create missing directories
    try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(foo, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}`

You also might want to use the option `NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic` which first write to an auxiliary file first and then exchange the files if there were no errors